# Debugging callback functions in Javascript: second function isn't reached

Tags: javascript, css, callback

I'm writing a website in vanilla javascript (can't use JQuery), where I've written a little fadeOut function with javascript and CSS. I'd like for the fadeOut to finish before the next function is called. To do this, I'm trying to use a callback function -- the only purpose of the function is to ensure the first function completes before the second is called. I've read several tutorials, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong -- I never arrive at the second function:

```
function mformSubmit() {
    doCallback(fadeOut, function() { setupM });
}

function fadeOut () {
    for(var i=0; i<m_types.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(m_types[i]).className != 'selected') {
           document.getElementById(m_types[i]).style.opacity = 0;
        } else {
            selection = m_types[i]; }
       };
}

function doCallback(callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}

function setupM() {
    alert("I arrived in the setup function");
}
```

And the relevant CSS bits:

```
label.unselected {
background-color: #fff;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid #CCC;
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.04) 15px 15px;
margin: 10px 10px 20px 30px;
/* Opacity tricks */
-webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease;
-moz-transition: opacity 800ms ease;
-o-transition: opacity 800ms ease;
transition: opacity 800ms ease;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `doCallback` only recognizes one parameter.  The second function passed in is ignored.

Comment: You might as well answer the question:)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need for a callback at all, it's all synchronous, and your callback won't wait for the CSS animations to finish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doCallback(callback)`, it's clear that it accepts one argument `callback`. Here's the fix which still won't work.

```
function doCallback(mainFn, callback) {
    if (typeof mainFn === "function") {
        mainFn();
    }        
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

The correct way is to set the callback on `fadeOut()`, and you don't need to nest you functions.

```
function fadeOut (callback) {
    for(var i=0; i<m_types.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(m_types[i]).className != 'selected') {
           document.getElementById(m_types[i]).style.opacity = 0;
        } else {
            selection = m_types[i]; }
       };
    // check if callback is function 
    if(typeof callback == 'function') callback();
}
```

And call it like:

```
fadeOut(function(){
   // code;
});

// or 

fadeOut(setupM); // note you don't need to pass ()
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! The examples I read and was emulating had an outer callback function, when in fact I wanted the fadeOut function itself to do the callback. Your fix worked exactly as I wanted to code to work. :D

Answer (score 0):

pass 2 Args to docallback(first,second)

call first(second)

inside first, on last line call second()

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly your `doCallback` function is only expecting a single parameter which, in the code you supplied, is just the fadeOut function. So fadeOut is the only function being called.

If I'm correct in understanding that you want to call the function `setupM` when the transition has completed, then you need to make use of either a timeout or the `transitionEnd` event listener. See:

```
element.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage, false);
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

That being the case, your javascript could be rewritten to be something like this:

```
function mformSubmit() {
    fadeOut();
}

function onTransitionEnd(event)
{
  event.target.removeEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionEnd);
  setupM();
}

function fadeOut () {
    for(var i=0; i<m_types.length; i++) {
        el = document.getElementById(m_types[i]);
        if (el.className != 'selected') {
          element.addEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionEnd, false);
          el.style.opacity = 0;
        } else {
            selection = m_types[i]; }
       };
}

function setupM() {
    alert("I arrived in the setup function");
}
```

Be aware that transitionend will not work in all browser, check the support table in the link above and compare that to your requirements.

All of this assumes, as I said above, that you want the second function to run after the initial transition is complete (and bear in mind that it will run for every element that you're fading out, in this instance). If you just want the second function to run after the first, then the above answers will suit you better.